# macOS: Change language of bash

Tags: bash, macos

How can I change the language settings for my macOS bash (only for the bash, not for the whole system) from German to English?

When compiling my C++ project with

```
cmake --build . --config Release --clean-first
```

I always obtain compile errors in German language and it really annoys me to translate them before googling.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably the errors don't come from bash; they will be produced by your compiler or other tools. Did you try setting the value of the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Should be enough. Here is a link for some [documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

If you want to go back to your native language, `unset LC_ALL` should work.

Best

Comment: And this can also be applied to individual commands: `LC_ALL=C cmake --build . --config Release --clean-first`